# How do I know if I hit with the tip of the sword?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

Marth's biggest trait is that the tip of his sword deals the most damage. Is there a way to know if I am hitting with it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only indication is that trail effect of attacks is brighter at the tip of Marth's sword, comparision between Brawl (top) and SSB4 (Bottom) below:

[image]

Based on that, you can get a better idea of where your attacks connect with the opponent. A general rule of thumb is to always play as far away as possible. A nice way to test this is actually in melee, where Roy was strongest when you connected with the broad of his sword, and Marth was with the tip. It actually led to some very different playstyles.

Reference to attack trail being brighter is [here.](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Marth_%28SSB4%29)

> Marth's attack trails are much brighter at the tip, making the
>   sweetspot of his attacks more visible than in previous games.

Comment: The top one looks like Brawl's Battlefield.

Answer (score 4):

The knockback and hit lag (the amount of time the opponent freezes in place) will be noticeably higher. The difference is especially pronounced on Smash attacks.

Reference: [Smashboards](http://smashboards.com/threads/1-0-4-marths-frame-data-wip.392027/)

Comment: Does the sound change?

Comment: At least for Smash attacks, it was different in Melee. I want to say "yes", but it's been some time since I last played SSB4 and I really can't recall off the top of my head.

Comment: It depends on the attack. For example, forward smash has 0.7x freeze frames and a Slash sound on the non-tipper, while it has 1.5x freeze frames, a Burn sound, and no SDI on the tipper. On the other hand, most of Marth's aerials instead have varying levels of Slash sounds (with the tip being the heaviest).

Comment: It's important to note that the base amount of hit lag is dependent on damage. So F-Smash has 70% the hit lag *of a 13% damage attack* on non-tip hits and 150% the hit lag *of an 18% damage attack* on tippers. Likewise, the damage factors into knockback calculations both directly and indirectly (the enemy will have higher % after a stronger hit). So the BKB and KBG values alone also don't tell the whole story.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you are hitting with it on the ground, the easiest way to tell that you hit is by the amount of time the opponent is frozen in place.

If using any kind of arial attack, the best way to tell is based on knockback.
For example, even at 50% or lower, if you land the tip on an up-air, there is a good chance the knockback will kill.